# Why is the SPARQL regex() function ignoring the "q" flag?

Tags: regex, sparql, jena, virtuoso, graphdb

I'm trying to test if a string is contained in another in a case-insensitive way. The SPARQL expression

```
REGEX ( ?str, ?tok, "iq" )
```

should do that. The `q` flag is needed in addition to the `i` flag because `?tok` may have regex special characters such as `[` or `\`. The REGEX should behave just like XQuery `fn:matches` function. However, including the `q` flag simply makes the expression return always false.
[update: it does not return false, it does not return a value at all]

Is this an issue in the GraphDB implementation I'm using or have I misinterpreted the standard? Has anyone observed this oddity in other SPARQL implementations?

I can work around this specific case by replacing it with

```
CONTAINS ( LCASE(?str), LCASE(?tok) )
```

but other scenarios which may need flags `x`, `s` and `m` do not seem to have an easy replacement. [update: the other flags all work correctly, only `q` is broken]

[note: the workaround with `lcase()` is suboptimal; `regex` should be more efficient.]

How do other triple stores behave in this respect?

Comment: Not sure, I tried with Virtuoso and `q` flag seems to be ignored as well : `select * where {
VALUES ?str {"abcd"}
VALUES ?pattern {".*"}
VALUES ?flags {"i" "iq"}
BIND(REGEX ( ?str, ?pattern, ?flags ) as ?matches)
}`

Comment: In GraphDB, it is not ignored. Flags i, s, m and x are behaving as expected, but flag q — alone or in conjunction with others — makes any pattern utterly unmatchable.
 
In fact, I tried inspecting the regex return value as you did, and it doesn't even return false, it simply fails to execute, returning nothing at all. I suspect it raises an exception, but the main log reveals nothing.

Comment: Hm. I managed to try it in Jena TDB/Fuseki and it worked as expected. Looks like it is really a GraphDB issue. A appreciate feedback from other triple stores users. Thx

Comment: I had a quick look and there turns out to be  a bug in the RDF4J SPARQL engine for regex evaluation, which causes the 'q' flag to not be recognized. See https://github.com/eclipse/rdf4j/issues/2224 . I'm suspecting that GraphDB relies on RDF4J's implementation for regex handling, and therefore has the same problem.

Comment: Fix is scheduled for the next RDF4J patch release.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra fast support as usual, very impressive. And to be honest, I wasn't even aware of such a flag `q` until now. Never digged into the REGEX specs of XPath, always happy to learn. Cheers

Comment: Thanks, guys, for clarifying, an Jeen for the promp fix.

Comment: I didn't know REGEX should support `qismx`, thanks! But why do you think that "regex should be more efficient" than `lcase`?

Comment: @UninformedUser — Would you mind [logging the issue to the Virtuoso project on github](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues)? If you still have your test rig for this (which I presume is more than the query in the comment above), that would be quite helpful to include!

Comment: Alexiev, the solution with contains() must first convert both strings with lcase and then compare the resulting strings, while a well implemented regex() can convert the characters just as needed (short-circuiting results) or even apply some more smart optimization. To compare Unicode strings you also need do normalise on.the.fly, and this is not a simple or cheap task. Surely not every regex implementation is well optimized, but they should be —  it affects performance when dealing with long strings. Most C/C++ implementations would use IBM's ICU to do this; Java has it built-in.

Answer (score 0):

This is a compliance problem in RDF4J, which is fixed in upcoming version 3.2.2. 
GraphDB, which uses RDF4F, shall incorporate the correction in sequence. 
The Jena/Fuseki implementation is already compliant in this repect.
The Virtuoso implementation seems to be broken as well (flag is ignored). 
There were no conformance reports for other implementations.

Comment: Jaccoud — Would you mind [logging the issue to the Virtuoso project on github](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues)? If you still have your test rig for this (which I presume is more than the query in @UninformedUser's comment above), that would be quite helpful to include!